# Error 500 preview not being shown on Chrome only on Postman

Tags: angular, google-chrome, http

I`m developing an Angular 4 app with .net core api, when I get error 500 I can see the detailed error on Postman, but not in Preview Tab of Chrome, is there a way to see it on Chrome Preview too?

Error 500 on Postman, shows the root error
[image]

Error 500 on Chrome, white preview
[image]

Comment: Did you see the `Response` tab ?

Comment: It shows "This request has no response data available"

Comment: You are trying the call directly the 5003 port while hosting the app on the 4200 ?

Comment: Yes, the api is on port 5003 and the consumer is on 4200, both localhost. The api is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security purpose, you can't call another url than the one hosting your app. For more information you can see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Create a `proxy.conf.json` in the root folder of your angular project :

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5003",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

And start your dev server with the `--proxy-config` option :

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Then can call your api using the same port `http://localhost:4200/api/*`.